# How do I prevent a duplicate random number when using setInterval? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, random, setinterval

I've been wanting to generate random numbers through a function and then use setInterval to repeat that function and give me a new number every time.

```
function randNum(prevNum) { 
    let randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 12)     //choose a number between 0 and 12 
    while (randNum == prevNum){                //if the chosen number is the same as prevNum, choose another random number
        randColor = Math.round(Math.random() * 12) 
    }
    prevNum = randColor            //assign current value to parameter 
    return (prevNum);              //return parameter
}


prevNum = 0,
prevNum = setInterval (randNum, 1000, prevNum)     //assign returned parameter to current variable, then go back into the function with the new parameter value.
```

also using node so semicolons might be missing.

Comment: It'll be difficult to not get a duplicate after 12 numbers...

Comment: @thebjorn It looks like just just doesn't want consecutive duplicates.

Comment: Note that your method of getting the random number is biased away from 0 and 12. You should use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `prevNum` as a `setInterval()` argument, you're always passing the original value of the variable to the callback function. You should just use the global variable directly rather than passing it as a parameter.

You also have a typo, `randColor` should be `randNum`.

```js
let prevNum = 0;

function randNum() {
  let newNum
  while (true) {
    newNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 12) //choose a number between 0 and 12 
    if (newNum != prevNum) {
      break;
    }
  }
  prevNum = newNum //save the current value
  console.log(prevNum);
}

let interval = setInterval(randNum, 1000)
```

The return value of the callback function isn't used, so there's no point in `return prevNum;`. And you shouldn't assign the result of `setInterval()` to your number variable -- it returns a timer ID, not the value of the function.

Comment: @thebjorn Thanks, I've renamed the variable to `newNum`.

Comment: @thebjorn I've been avoiding do-while since long before Python was a thing. I just find it confusing because I don't see the condition up front. There are very few situations where it's the right construct.

Comment: Way back when Python was considering adding a similar construct, I did an analysis of the C-code we had at work (we produced c/c++ libraries). Of all uses of while loops, only 3% were in do/while loops...

Comment: @thebjorn I'll believe it. I don't usually see them in any of our production code, but for some reason they show up frequently in SO. And most of them are inappropriate IMHO.

Comment: I am the 3%....

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that returns an iterator and keeps the state:

```
function randiter(n) {
    let num = 0;

    const iter = () => {
        let cur;
        do {
            cur = Math.round(Math.random() * n);
        } while (cur === num);
        num = cur;
        return num;
    };
    return iter;
}
```

The above version takes the max number as a parameter. Use it like so:

```
const p12 = randiter(12);

for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
    console.log(p12());
}
```

or

```
setInterval(() => console.log(p12()), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I  am the 3%
(and I miss Pascal)

```js
let intervalRef = setInterval( ( prev ) =>
  {
  let newNum;
  do     newNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 12) 
  while( newNum === prev.val )

  prev.val = newNum

  console.log( newNum )
  }
  , 1000, { val: null } )
  
  
setTimeout(()=>clearInterval(intervalRef), 20000)
```